# Google Chrome connecting to websocket in pre-loaded page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket

In my website I have a websocket connection that sends info to the server in case the visitor is turning idle(not moving the mouse or pressing a key) after x seconds.
Everything is working ok, but I saw a strange behavior on google chrome (version 37 and now 38 - currently latest stable version) on windows 7(probably others operating systems too).

The visitor is connecting to the websocket before the page loads (before hits enter in the address bar). Digging the problem I found this this http://readwrite.com/2012/01/05/new_chrome_will_load_web_pages_before_you_hit_ente

> If you're typing in a site you visit all the time, and the address
>   auto-completes, Chrome will begin pre-rendering the page, reducing
>   load time.

More about Instant Pages on google blog http://chrome.blogspot.ro/2011/08/instant-pages-on-google-chrome.html

Everything is great but there is a problem, google loads the page after I typed the 3rd key from my website name assuming I want to visit that website, and a websocket connection to my server is made, and the connection will be available for hours even if I don't hit enter, even if I change the text in the address bar.

Another problem is when there are other sites with the name similar to mine.
For example I want to visit cooldogs.com . I go to address bar and start typing cool and 2 sites appear coolcats.com and cooldogs.com . Because coolcats.com is the first website, chrome will pre-load that site, connect to the websocket even though I wanted to visit cooldogs.com
Note: coolcats.com and cooldogs.com are invented names

So my question is how to make google chrome connect to the websocket server only after the user hits enter and the website is loaded. I'm not interested in a google chrome configuration because I can't educate all my visitors to change settings.

Is this a bug or a design flow?

Comment: Where in the DOM lifecicle are you making that websocket connection?

Comment: after the window is loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the [Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API) to just start the WS connection if the page is visible.

> The Page Visibility API lets you know when a webpage is visible or in
>   focus. With tabbed browsing, there is a reasonable chance that any
>   given webpage is in the background and thus not visible to the user.
>
> The API is particularly useful for saving resources by giving
>   developers the opportunity to not perform unnecessary tasks when the
>   webpage is not visible.
>
> Use cases
>
> A few examples:
>
> - A site has an image carousel that shouldn't advance to the next slide
>     unless the user is viewing the page.
> - An application showing a
>     dashboard of information doesn't want to poll the server for updates
>     when the page isn't visible.
> - **A page wants to detect when it is being
>     prerendered** so it can keep accurate count of page views.

It would be something like:

```
if(document.hidden === undefined || !document.hidden){
     // start WS connection
}
document.addEventListener("visibilityChange", function(){

     if( !webSocketStarted && (document.hidden !== undefined && !document.hidden){
        // start WS connection
     }

}, false);
```

Read the doc, and give it a try.